# How can I download several thousand files from a page that requires specifications?

Tags: download-manager

I'm a marketing researcher looking to analyze temperature data from every county across the US, there are ~3200. The site from which I want to download data requires the user to enter info into drop down menus as well as writing in text to specify what data, in what time range, and the location. Here's the URL: https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/search

What I'd like to do is automate this process so I don't have to spend sixty hours just downloading files. I have basically no programming experience, a tiny bit of HTML and have used command line to run wget. It seems wget isn't feasible here as the website sends an email with a link to the file download, and does not have a list of URLs.

I am a pretty good learner, though. Is it possible that I could figure out how to crack this problem in a week or two (using Windows 10), having been pointed in the right direction? If not, would someone with more experience be able to write a script to do this and how much would be a reasonable amount to pay them to do so?

Any help at all is great, thanks a lot.

Comment: It looks like you will need to start with figuring out how to access the API: https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2#gettingStarted

Comment: If I have the base URL as a starting point, can I put the request script straight into my system command prompt?